# New versions of srep failing my compression algorithm

Tags: compression

**I am currently using freearc, precomp042 and srep 3.2**

I use 4 regular compressions styles as noted below depending on data type and have no problem. I recently tried using srep 3.9, 3.91 and 3.92. All compress OK but fail immediately on decompression with an srep l256 error

What can I change to allow the new version to work and is it possible to improve compression. I have 8gb RAM and compression time is not a problem for me

Many thanks

```
arc a -ep1 -ed -r -w Archive(A1).bin -mx -mc-delta -mc:lzma/lzma:192mb:normal:bt4:192:mc10000:lc8 -ld192m -mc:rep/srep:l256 -mc$default,$obj:+precomp042:c-:t-j:intense -s -x Archive\*.*

arc a -ep1 -ed -r -w Archive(A2).bin -mx -mc:lzma/lzma:max:512mb -mc:exe/exe2 -mc:rep/maxsrep -mc$default,$obj:+maxprecompj -x Archive\*.*

arc a -ep1 -ed -r -w Archive(A3).arc -msrep+lzma:a1:mfbt4:d256m:fb128:mc1000:lc8 -x Archive\*.*

arc a -ep1 -ed -r -w Archive(A4).bin -mprecomp:zl69:d0:t-jnf+srep+lzma:a1:mfbt4:d256m:fb128:mc1000:lc8 -x Archive\*.*
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a programming question in here. It seems to be about using pre-built software. Stack Overflow is for programming questions, questions about generic hardware and software belong to Super User (or one of the specialized user sites).

Comment: Sorry, found your site useful on occasion and thought i'd give it a go. Can you point me in the right direction of another site perhaps? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here mate, try this. Its the most powerful compression without messing around many external compressors.

```
-mprecomp+srep:m3f:a1:l256+lzma:a1:mfbt4:d200m:fb128:mc1000:lc8
```